# Problem with applying 8x8 texture on quad (it is very blured)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

## The problem

I am having problem in Unity3d with rendering 8x8px texture on simple quad from texture atlas (32x32) using uvs coordinates.
When I apply texture on quad using my code, then it is very blured. Probably unity is scaling 8x8 image to much bigger size. How to render 8x8 texture on quad propetly?

I was trying to find solution but with any positive result. I am beginner and I do not exactly know how unity is rendering textures.

## My code

This is how I am setting material:

```
    private void LoadData() {
        if (blockType == BlockType.AIR) {
            this.isSolid = false;
            return;
        }
        this.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
        Texture2D texture2D =  Resources.Load("Textures/" + blockType) as Texture2D;
        this.material.mainTexture = texture2D;
    }
```

Here is my BuildQuad function (define uvs):

```
    public void BuildQuad(CubeSide cubeSide) {
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.name = "QuadMesh";
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[4];
        Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[4];
        Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[4];
        int[] triangles = new int[6];
        if (cubeSide == CubeSide.FRONT) {
            vertices = new Vector3[] {p4, p5, p1, p0};
            normals = new Vector3[] {
                Vector3.forward, 
                Vector3.forward, 
                Vector3.forward, 
                Vector3.forward
            };
            uvs = new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(0.25f, 0.25f),
                new Vector2(0.0f, 0.25f),
                new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f),
                new Vector2(0.25f, 0),
            };
        } else if (cubeSide == CubeSide.BACK) {
            vertices = new Vector3[] {p6, p7, p3, p2};
            normals = new Vector3[] {
                Vector3.back, 
                Vector3.back, 
                Vector3.back, 
                Vector3.back
            };
            uvs = new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(0.5f, 0.25f), 
                new Vector2(0.251f, 0.25f), 
                new Vector2(0.251f, 0.0f), 
                new Vector2(0.5f, 0.0f),  
            };
        } else if (cubeSide == CubeSide.LEFT) {
            vertices = new Vector3[] {p7, p4, p0, p3};
            normals = new Vector3[] {
                Vector3.left, 
                Vector3.left, 
                Vector3.left, 
                Vector3.left
            };
            uvs = new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(0.75f, 0.25f),
                new Vector2(0.501f, 0.25f),
                new Vector2(0.501f, 0.0f), 
                new Vector2(0.75f, 0.0f),
            };
        } else if (cubeSide == CubeSide.RIGHT) {
            vertices = new Vector3[] {p5, p6, p2, p1};
            normals = new Vector3[] {
                Vector3.right, 
                Vector3.right, 
                Vector3.right, 
                Vector3.right
            };
            uvs = new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(1.0f, 0.25f),
                new Vector2(0.751f, 0.25f),
                new Vector2(0.751f, 0.0f), 
                new Vector2(1.00f, 0.0f),
            };
        } else if (cubeSide == CubeSide.BOTTOM) {
            vertices = new Vector3[] {p0, p1, p2, p3};
            normals = new Vector3[] {
                Vector3.down, 
                Vector3.down, 
                Vector3.down, 
                Vector3.down
            };
            uvs = new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(0.25f, 0.50f),
                new Vector2(0.0f, 0.50f),
                new Vector2(0.0f, 0.251f), 
                new Vector2(0.25f, 0.251f),
            };
        } else if (cubeSide == CubeSide.TOP) {
            vertices = new Vector3[] {p7, p6, p5, p4};
            normals = new Vector3[] {
                Vector3.up, 
                Vector3.up, 
                Vector3.up, 
                Vector3.up
            };
            uvs = new Vector2[] {
                new Vector2(0.50f, 0.50f),
                new Vector2(0.251f, 0.5f),
                new Vector2(0.251f, 0.251f), 
                new Vector2(0.5f, 0.251f),
            };
        }
        triangles = new int[] {3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1};
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.normals = normals;
        mesh.uv = uvs;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        GameObject quad = new GameObject("quad");
        quad.transform.position = location.position;
        quad.transform.parent = parent.transform;
        MeshFilter meshFilter = (MeshFilter) quad.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter));
        meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
    }
```

And here is how I am setting material to renderer

```
    void CombineQuads() {

        //1. Combine all children meshes
        MeshFilter[] meshFilters = chunkGameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
        CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < meshFilters.Length) {
            combine[i].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
            combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            i++;
        }

        //2. Create a new mesh on the parent object
        MeshFilter meshFilter = (MeshFilter) chunkGameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter));
        meshFilter.mesh = new Mesh();

        //3. Add combined meshes on children as the parent's mesh
        meshFilter.mesh.CombineMeshes(combine);

        //4. Create a renderer for the parent
        MeshRenderer renderer = chunkGameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer)) as MeshRenderer;
        renderer.material = BlockData.GetBlockData(BlockType.DIRT).material;

        //5. Delete all uncombined children
        foreach (Transform quad in chunkGameObject.transform) {
            GameObject.Destroy(quad.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

## Result

I use this image to render dirt block by rendering quads on all sides:
[image: 32x32 dirt quads atlas]

And here is not wanted result (with blur):
[image: blur]

I completly do not know how to avoid this. Where is the problem?
How to make it to look like this:
[image: wanted result]

Comment: `texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;` or set in the inspector?

Comment: @gman That's it! Thank you so much! Can not believe it was that simple! If you will post answer, then I will mark it as solution :)